# How can I get cmake command from cmake-gui?

Tags: cmake

I use cmake-gui to configure OpenCV, and I want to use same configure on some other computer.
Cause I use ssh without X forwarding, so I can't use cmake-gui to configure again.
I don't kown how to use cmake to complete my configure, so I wonder that cmake-gui can generate the command use for cmake?
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why not use ccmake then? It provides pretty much the same functionality as cmake-gui (minus the mouse support) and works fine over ssh.

Comment: I want to use bash to parallel do this thing without manually control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option called: `Tools-> Show my Changes` which displays exactly what you have configured relating to the original configuration. One version are the copy&paste command line parameters and the other version is nicely human readable.

Answer (score 1):

By default you cannot do what you want because that path is stored in `CMAKE_COMMAND` which is an INTERNAL variable so it is not visible in the GUI. You can manually read it from the cache using a command like <kbd>grep CMAKE_COMMAND CMakeCache.txt | cut -d = -f 2</kbd>. Alternatively you can update your `CMakeLists.txt` to put the value of `CMAKE_COMMAND` in the cache so that you can read it using the GUI. For example:

```
set(USED_CMAKE_PATH ${CMAKE_COMMAND} CACHE FILEPATH
    "The path to the CMake executable used to configure this project" FORCE)
```

Additionally if you are using the "Unix Makefiles" generator there are two targets provided for this:

- `rebuild_cace` which is equivalent to <kbd>cmake .</kbd>
- `edit_cache` which is equivalent to <kbd>ccmake .</kbd> or <kbd>cmake-gui .</kbd> depending upon your install.

*Note:* I used CMake version 2.8.10.2 to test this, but I expect it to work with any version.